# Aligning controls better for Better ui design look and feel understanding of stacks

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get my controls in a. nice boarded box but I can't seem to fit them it could be my circle size in my progressive but could be just my understanding of my stacks, I am just new to swift ui after using .net C sharp for many years.

This is my main view

```
import SwiftUI

struct CaloriesView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack  {
        ProgressRingView()
    }
    
    ZStack{

        Label("Base Goals", systemImage: "folder.circle").font(.system(size: 30))
    }
    
    HStack{
        
        Label("Daily Limit", systemImage: "flag.fill").font(.system(size: 30))
        
        Label("Food", systemImage: "fork.knife").font(.system(size: 30))
    }
    HStack{
        Label("Exercise Taken", systemImage: "flag.fill").font(.system(size: 30))
    }
}
}

struct CaloriesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
     CaloriesView()
 }
}
```

But what am looking moreis the progress ring to the left and the icons properly aligned to the right

[image]

This is my circle how I create it in my progress view

```
Import SwiftUI 
struct ProgressRingView: View {
@State var progress = 0.0
let colors: [Color] = [.yellow, .red,.blue, .purple]

var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            // MARK:Place Holder Ring
            Circle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 20)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .opacity(0.1)
            
            // MARK: Colored Ring
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: min(progress,1.0))
                .stroke(  AngularGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors), center: .center,startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360 + 45)) ,style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 15, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                .rotationEffect((Angle(degrees: 270)))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0),value:progress)
                .onAppear{
                    progress=1
                }
            
            VStack(spacing:30)
            {
                //MARK : Elapsed Time
                
                VStack(spacing:5)
                {
                    Text("Calories")
                        .opacity(0.7)
                }
                .padding(.top)
                
                //MARK :Remiaing Time
                
                VStack(spacing:5)
                {
                    Text("Rmaining ")
                        .opacity(0.7)
                    
                    Text("0:00")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
        .padding()
                        }
                        }
                        
            struct ProgressRingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgressRingView()
    }
}
```

Edit

To show the style of what am looking for its kinda like my fitness pal but not exactly the same.

[image]

Comment: Can you sketch some mockup what do you want to achieve? I can say I understood the goal from the description.

Comment: @Asperi shown above its kinda like my fitness pal a bit if u have used it I'm just using it for learning purposes of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little playground app on the iPad to show how you might approach creating this view.

It's not perfect but hopefully will give you some pointers.

I've extracted a couple of the views into reusable components for you and added the title etc...

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Calories")
                    .font(.system(.largeTitle))
                
                Text("Remaining = Goal - Food + Exercise")
            }
            
            DataView()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.init(white: 0.05))
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}

struct DataView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            CircleView()
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                TagView(
                    image: .init(systemName: "flag.fill"), 
                    color: .gray,
                    title: "Base Goal",
                    number: 2300
                )
                
                TagView(
                    image: .init(systemName: "fork.knife"),
                    color: .blue,
                    title: "Food",
                    number: 0
                )
                
                TagView(
                    image: .init(systemName: "flame.fill"),
                    color: .orange,
                    title: "Exercise",
                    number: 0
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TagView: View {
    let image: Image
    let color: Color
    let title: String
    let number: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(color)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 30, alignment: .center)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(.subheadline))
                Text("\(number)")
                    .font(.system(.headline))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(
                    AngularGradient(colors: [.red, .green, .blue, .red], center: .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)),
                    lineWidth: 5
                )
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) { 
                Text("2300")
                    .font(.system(.title))
                
                Text("Remaining")
                    .font(.system(.caption))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this... [image]

Comment: Wow defo thanks so much ios community agaib just wows me ill give it a try. Amazing u can do it on ipad bow shows how far its become

Comment: Just a tad confused which View segment do I use to get the nice black frame? Please see code above when I try it I don't get the nice rounded corner black frame ?

Comment: never mind I got it I was missing the main chunk how it gets the view

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of HStack and a nested VStack to achieve a similar layout:

```swift
struct CaloriesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ProgressRingView()
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Label("Base Goals", systemImage: "folder.circle")
                Label("Daily Limit", systemImage: "flag.fill")
                Label("Food", systemImage: "fork.knife")
                Label("Exercise Taken", systemImage: "flag.fill")
            }
        }
            .padding()
    }
}
```

This is how the result looks like on an iPhone 13 simulator:
[image: Screenshot of a modified progress screen]

To make it look nicer, I also took the liberty of fixing a typo, removing a fixed font size of 30 from the labels and shrinking the frame of the `ProgressRingView` down to 150x150.

Note that in your original code you're using ZStacks and HStacks with just a single view inside them: that doesn't make much sense because the stack are supposed to lay out several items and they aren't useful for just a single item.

Now, on my screenshot you may notice that the texts of the labels aren't quite aligned, but I'd suggest to do it as a separate exercise because we're all here to learn. Happy SwiftUIing!

**Edit 2**
When I try the code below in answer I just get this what am a missing to get the nice black frame

[image]

Comment: I'm glad your problem was solved but I don't understand why you edited my answer by adding some of your own feedback instead of adding a comment. Currenty it looks like I'm talking to myself in my own answer which doesn't make much sense. Could you please revert it and add a comment instead?